# Setup localhost server on iOS device

Tags: ios, localhost, server

I have seen several iOS apps using a localhost such as

```
    http://localhost:12345
```

Which is accessed through Safari.

Any ideas about how this can be achieved ?

Thank you in advance.

Edit :

I just found CocoaHTTPServer at https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer that seems to do that.

Comment: I want to do the same in my app. Is it so difficult to imagine, r ?